# In Left Join of two table select all records from left table and select only one row record from right table that matches to left table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, limit

I have two tables Questions and Answers

I want to select all questions of maths subject but only single answer of the of the questions.

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('questions');
    $this->db->join('answers','questions.id = answers.que_id', 'left'); //how to limit answers to 1
    $this->db->where('questions.subject', 'maths');
    return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: why not just `$this->db->limit(1)` ?

Comment: it results only one question.

Comment: I want all the questions of subject with single answer from Answers table

Comment: If it was me, I'd resolve the problem in raw sql first, and then figure out how to transcribe it to your chosen framework

Comment: Please explain if you can in the above code.. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query,

select question,(select answer from answers where questions.id = answers.que_id) as answer from questions where questions.subject='maths';

Please note : This is not a running SQL - just get the idea

Comment: tried but not working
case 1:
      $this->db->join('answers','questions.id = (select que_id from answers where answers.que_id = questions.id limit 1)', 'left');

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery like this :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('answers');
$this->db->join('(select * from questions limit 1)','(questions.id = answers.que_id)', 'inner');
$this->db->where('questions.subject', 'maths');
return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Not working.
Showing same results as it showed before.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your query request

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
$query = 'select q.*, a1.* 
from questions AS q
    left join answers AS a1
        on a1.id = (select a2.id 
            from answers AS a2 
            where q.id = a2.que_id
            ORDER BY a2.id 
            limit 1
            );';
$query = $this->db->query($query);
$result = $query->result():
```